# LoadError (cannot load such file -- static_helper.rb):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upgrade an old rails 2.3 app to 2.3.15 and I'm getting the following error after changing the RAILS_GEM_VERSION line in environment.rb

```
LoadError (cannot load such file -- static_helper.rb):
app/controllers/static_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using bundler?  ( http://gembundler.com/rails23.html ).

I had a different error updating an old rails 2.3 app to 2.3.15 that I was able to work around by setting up bundler and removing `config.gem` lines from `config/environment.rb`

---

Nevermind that Bundler advice, I bet the `StaticController` expects to find a corresponding helper file.  Try creating a file called `app/helpers/static_helper.rb`:

```
module StaticHelper
end
```

Comment: I'm not using bundler with this old app